# "Unexpected ordering of clauses" error when exporting an Excel file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, export-to-csv, select-into

I need to export the result of a query to a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file in MySQL.

I wrote:

```
SELECT orders.user_id, orders.order_id, members.name, members.family,
       orders.agent_id, CONCAT(m.name, ' ', m.family) AS agent_name
  FROM orders
  JOIN members
    ON members.username=orders.user_id
  JOIN members m
    ON orders.agent_id=m.username
 WHERE order_status=4 and pay_method='verbalPayment'
   AND agent_id is not NULL
   AND order_time BETWEEN 1559935800 AND 1560596861
  INTO OUTFILE 'weekly_orders.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

But when I ran this query, I got this error:

> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Unexpected ordering of clauses. (near "FROM" at position 131)

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Where does Excel come in? Is the CSV file to be imported in Excel?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, the problem is the `INTO`, which should immediately follow the `SELECT`.  I would suggest writing the query as:

```
SELECT o.user_id, o.order_id, mu.name, mu.family, 
       o.agent_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', ma.name, ma.family) AS agent_name 
INTO OUTFILE 'weekly_orders.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
FROM orders o JOIN
     members mu
     ON mu.username = o.user_id JOIN
     members ma
     ON o.agent_id = ma.username 
 WHERE o.order_status = 4 AND
       o.pay_method = 'verbalPayment' AND
       o.order_time BETWEEN 1559935800 AND 1560596861 ;
```

Notes:

- The condition `agent_id is not NULL` is redundant.  The `JOIN` takes care of this.
- Alias all your tables.  `mu` for "member as user" and `ma` for "member as agent" is easier to understand.
- `CONCAT_WS()` works even when one of the names is `NULL`.
- I would also be inclined to convert the date constants from YYYY-MM-DD format to the Unix format, so the query is more easily understood (but you may understand what those numbers mean).

Comment: Re *"the problem is that the INTO follows the SELECT"*: Do you mean *"the problem is that the INTO* ***must follow*** *the SELECT"* (sort of the opposite)?

Answer (score 2):

Wrong *into* clause position:

```
  SELECT orders.user_id
    , orders.order_id
    , members.name
    , members.family
    , orders.agent_id
    , CONCAT(m.name, ' ', m.family) AS agent_name
    INTO OUTFILE 'weekly_orders.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    FROM orders
    JOIN members ON members.username=orders.user_id
    join members m on orders.agent_id=m.username
    where order_status=4
    and pay_method='verbalPayment'
    and agent_id is not NULL and order_time between 1559935800 and 1560596861
```

Comment: What is the reason? What rules apply? Please respond by editing your answer, not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

If you have the former versions of the database such as `5.6`,`5.7`.. etc, then `INTO` clause need to precede `FROM` clause, unless a trailing locking clause such as `FOR UPDATE` or `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` is used. Putting `INTO` clause to the end of the statement is supported, and positioning it before a locking clause is deprected starting from the version `8.0.20`.

Therefore, seems you're currently using a former version of the database, and need to prefer the following reordered syntax :

```
....INTO OUTFILE 'weekly_orders.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    FROM orders ....
```

Comment: *Why* is that required? Please respond by editing your answer, not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).